# Wordpress does not load js files on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

after long time of ripping hair of my head I came to point that I don't have any anymore.

I am developing wordpress site and everything works well except on mobile devices. When site is opened on mobile my js file is not loaded at all. When I put js to script tags to the footer as well it works properly.

I use similar script on another pages where everything works well.

I have script declared in functions // loads well on desktop so it should work

```
 wp_register_script( 'main-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-core' ), '2', true );
wp_enqueue_script('main-js');
```

I am also calling wp_footer() in the footer.

site is on http://wp.jarmill.com/clients/imranabram

Every help is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't see a problem on Firefox/Android. Is there a particular device that has problems?

Comment: Hi I am on my Android device default browser and client was on the iPhone. Can you verify if the mobile menu is working and slider?

Answer (score 0):

So I debugged on android where I got unexpected ")" error, went through the code but did not find anything.

Problem was in google maps functions which was called for different page so I moved the mapInit script to the specific page to script tags and now it works everywhere.

It might not be the cleanest solution but for now it works.